# How do I calculate the URL to the root of a PHP script?

Tags: php

I have the following URL:

> http://localhost/mysite.loc/web/app_dev.php/blah/blah/blah

I need to calculate the root URL to the app_dev.php script. The result for the above should be:

> http://localhost/mysite.loc/web/

which will serve as the base path for images, in order to make their paths absolute.

How do I go about calculating the above path, and cater for different setups, vhosts etc?

I hope this is making sense! :)

Comment: Absolute path for images is bad idea. Instead of just being a "hit" , your image will generate a new request on the server which degrade performance.  If it's absolutely mandatory for you , just write the base url in a configuration file.

Comment: @grunk what "hit" you're talking about and how it differs from the "new request"?

Comment: @grunk *every* path gets turned into an absolute path when it leaves the browser. What are you talking about?

Comment: I was thinking that a absolute uri will fire an extra dns lookup , but if the browser convert relative to absolute it should be no difference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like this is what I needed:

```
$url = strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'], '443') !== false ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$split = preg_split('%/|\\\\%i', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$url = preg_split("/{$split[count($split)-1]}/i", $url);
```

Did the trick, I just need to test it now.

Answer (score 0):

The [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) will likely give you what you are looking for. If I am interpreting what you are asking correctly then you can do something like:

`$host = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

`$dir = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');`

Then `echo $host.$dir` should give you your base path to which you can add whatever path you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it in `app_dev.php` its very easy:

```
$dir = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/";
```

Note you don't need http://localhost/ part, it's silly.

Answer (score -1):

As simple as: `$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`

To get the [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FQDN) you would have to do something like so:

```
$path = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);'
```

this would produce the results like so:

```
http://localhost/mysite.loc/web/
https://localhost/mysite.loc/web/
```

Comment: Your first answer was wrong. Please edit it an i'll remove the down vote.

Comment: @Pekka: For this: "As simple as: $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];".

Comment: @Pekka, That's why i said: "Your first answer was wrong. Please edit it an i'll remove the down vote."

Comment: @Pekka, I can't. It says me that my vote is blocked until he edits it's answer. I didn't unvoted it immediately, I was browsing other questions in the meanwhile...

Comment: @Charlie ah. Fixed that for you, it should be possible now.

Comment: I did rush to place an answer and i admit that it might not have been 100% correct, the answer as update within a few minutes of posting